# Setting a global DB connection in Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Are there suggested ways to set a global connection in Google App Engine? The approach I am currently using seems a bit crude, and I'm doing it like this:

```
import pymysql
from flask import Flask, jsonify

# lazy loading?
db_conn = None
db_cursor = None

def get_db():
    global db_conn, db_cursor
    if (db_conn, db_cursor) == (None, None):
        global_conn = pymysql.connect(user="x", password="y", database="z", host="w", charset='utf8')
        global_cursor = conn.cursor()
    return (db_conn, db_cursor)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return jsonify(hello='world')

@app.route('/db')
def db():
    conn, cursor = get_db()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 50")
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    return res
```

Comment: See example from Google - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/app.py. They also recommend you use a connection pool - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#best-practices

Comment: @NoCommandLine oh fantastic, yes that is exactly what I was looking for -- want to elaborate on that in an answer and I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because DB connections can be dropped for one reason or the other, Google recommends using a connection pool for connecting to DBs (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#best-practices)).
2. They also have a [worked example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/app.py) for a global connection which is part of a connection pool. In the linked example, you will note that they included comments to invoke the connection as soon as your App is loaded instead of when a request is first made

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad. However, if you always need your Database connection in your instance, soon or later, you can directly start your db connection at runtime

```
import pymysql
from flask import Flask, jsonify

# eager loading?
db_conn = pymysql.connect(user="x", password="y", database="z", host="w", charset='utf8')
db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)
...
```

The code is simpler, but it will impact your startup time. No worries if you need DB connection at a time. But can be bad if many of your endpoints don't need DB access. it's up to you, as always, it depends!